# Alternating Colours for dynamic menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, opencart

I am working on an Opencart site and for the categories on the left hand side I need them to alternate in different colours eg. red, purple, green, blue etc and then repeating when more categories are added to the menu.

Can anyone give me advice of the easiest way to do this?

You can view the site below:
http://getsmarta.co/_ecommerce/easy-leaf/

Comment: If you're not concerned with older browser compatibility I would go the nth child CSS route. See http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ for ref. If you are concerned with people using older browsers (I don't think IE8 supports nth child) I would definitely go the server side route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var color = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow'];

            $('ul#test').find('li').each(function (i) {
                $(this).addClass(color[((i + 3) % 3)]);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Red
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }

        .Green
        {
            background-color: Green;
        }

        .Yellow
        {
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="test">
        <li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
        <li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
        <li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
        <li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Opencart, but can't this be achieved with css? You can most likely use the n-th child thing to make this work.
Or you can colour it by using jquery, using a for loop and a class name of colour1, colour2 and so on. Loop through the number of colours and addClass() to each element.
There are probably better solutions these are just what came up now.

Edit: ok maybe the n-th child won't be good for earlier browsers so the jquery solution would be good unless you want to add the colour class in the page itself using the same concept as the jquery

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this server side.

In part code / part comments that you'll need to fill in:

```
$i = 0;
// loop through rows
$i++;
$alt=false;
if ($i % 2 == 0) {
 $alt = true;
}
// output row
// make sure to use a if ($alt) { echo 'class="alt""'; } or something similar so you can style away
// end loop
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not giving you the code. Write it yourself. Here is the idea.

1. Write 4 classes for 4 different colors.
2. Now write a function to add correct class to each `li` item. ie, you
   can check the li item's position and add correct class to it.

You can use either javascript or php to do this.
Now the link color will change automatically with new categories adding.